# OpenLayers popup not closing on mobile device

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, mobile

I am developing an app that should also work on mobile devices.
I would like to close all open popups when clicking on the map (in this case only one can be open at any point, as opening a new one closes all existing ones; therefore referring to index 0 in the code snippet below).

The event has been registered like this:

```
itemsMap.events.register("click", itemsMap , function(e){
   closeOpenPopups();
});
```

And here is the function that takes care of it:

```
function closeOpenPopups(){
    // close popup if existent
    if(itemsMap.popups[0]){itemsMap.removePopup(itemsMap.popups[0]);}

    // unselect all features
    control_select_feature_showItem.unselectAll();
}
```

This works perfectly fine when testing it on non-mobile devices, but the popup just won't close on mobile devices. The strange thing: the unselectAll() works fine, so I guess I can assume that the click event is changed into a tapping event when using a mobile device (or that method would never be fired, right?).

Comment: I don't believe that goog.events has a different click event between mobile and other computing devices. If you could put up a complete working example in jsfiddle or similar, it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would test if the click event is fired on the mobile device (for example with a simple alert)
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/n68f7jus/
[image]

( and make sure you are using a up to date version of OpenLayers like 2.13 )

If you are using the popup for a vector layer you could try if this example works on your mobile device (vector style not even optimized for mobile devices)

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/rk5puxp2/

[image]